# Dual WAN Router w/Failover for < 50 IP Network Recommendation

Tags: vpn, router, failover, wide-area-network

Looking for a good dual WAN (for failover, don't care about load balancing) router for a small network (<50 devices). I don't want anything home-grown - has to be commercially supported hardware.

Some requirements:

- VPN from this device to Cisco ASA5510
  (both WAN interfaces)
- DHCP
- Wired WAN failover
- < $500
- 10/100 (1000 would be nice)

Nice to have:
 - "stackable" or otherwise support device failover

I've considered:

- NetGear FVS336G
- Cisco RV042
- SonicWall TZ200

But they are all about the "same" as far as features are concerned. Thoughts? What have people used?

Edit: Please say in what context you had your device deployed. Home office aint big enough :D Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using Cisco I would just stick with that.  Assuming you don't already have a bunch of assorted equipment... Put on your management hat and figure in the future the company can hire someone who knows 'Cisco'.  Also, if you are having any issues with the VPN between the two, Cisco will support both ends.

Although, I have never used SonicWall so maybe the configuration is very similar and Netgear is similar, it generally easier to have the same stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a "bunch of assorted equipment"; however the Cisco RV042 is basically a re-badged LinkSys so the single-brand advantage doesn't really apply

Comment: Linksys _is_ Cisco.

Comment: Right, but the OS is Linksys -- not the same as the Cisco ASA product line; so the "knows Cisco" thing isn't really that useful. I would agree if we were looking at buying another ASA vs. something else

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a [Peplink Balance](http://www.peplink.com) for over 2 years now, and the router's failover has been working flawlessly. Their low end model should fit your budget.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Linksys/Cisco RV042 for several years in commercial locations as you have described with good success.  The only thing from your list I have not done is a P2P VPN to a Cisco ASA, but I do use the built-in PPTP VPN for remote access.

This model is currently our recommendation for customers of our SAAS product.

Edit:  We use the RV016 because it has more switch ports and can therefore be considered as an all-in-one device.

Comment: Keith, thanks for the reply. How many clients max ?

Comment: In-house 10-12 clients max.  As I remember we do have a customer site with 30+.

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a good experience with [Xincom](http://www.xincom.com/) products over a period of 3.5 years. Worked flawlessly and never needed attention.

Answer (score 1):

Barracuda Link balancer : http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/balancers.php

Answer (score 1):

Like another comment, we too have used the Linksys RV082 (in between the rv016 and rv042). This one is a 8 port switch. We used it as a failover device.

I know your request said you didn't care about load balancing, but I thought I'd also comment with our recent experience with loan balancing in case someone stumbles accross this post looking for that information.

The load balancing works, but is very primitive. As far as I call tell, it's per packet load balancing. This wrecks havoc with many SSL websites that expect packets to be coming from the same IP. We've "solved" this by using the devices ability to bind https traffic to a specific WAN connection, but that effectively negates the load balancing features.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to include [FatPipe](http://www.fatpipeinc.com/) in your product evaluations.  They have several solutions that may meet your needs, though I'm not sure about the price.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [Hotbricks](http://www.hotbrick.com/produto.asp?tipo=3&catpro=2) in the past. The Firewall VPN 800/2 should be within that price range, but you may need to find it on ebay. It looks like they are out of stock on it now.